# Alterar valor default de um boolean em um select ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, checkbox

Tenho um campo  no meu sistema que precisa informar se o produto está ou não disponível, no SQL está como bit( TRUE ou FALSE).

o EntityFramework gerou uma View com um SELECT True ou False.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alugada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alugada)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ativa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como personalizo os campos True e False?

Comment: Você teria o acesso a criação desse form no front? Caso tenha você pode verificar a opção do select, vou postar uma resposta com o meu exemplo, porém o form é gerado por mim, não sei se é possivel

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei um form e adicionei os mesmos campos para teste, espero que funcione.

Na hora que iniciar o form coloquei para que ele crie uma lista de string e adicione como dataSource da list.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> situacao = new List<string>();
        situacao.Add("Ativo");
        situacao.Add("Inativo");
        lstSituacao.DataSource = situacao;
        lstSituacao.DataBind();
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai quando mandar para o banco você faz a validação e troca, que ficaria no button.

> Caso tenha acesso ao `BACK` do form e `FRONT` eu conseguiria
>   modifica-lo porém tem apenas um deles.